# Prevent an application from making any network access on macOS

Tags: network, firewalls, macos, sandbox

I want to run an application on macOS, but preventing it from making any type of network access, or any type of internet access.

I have seen the following possibilities:

- Use the built-in firewall. Unfortunately, this blocks only inbound connections, not outbound.
- I have seen Little Snitch. However, it feels uncomfortable from a security standpoint to install a closed-source software on my system that has so deep an access to everything I do.

Ideally, I would like to do that myself. Is it possible to restrict an app's access to network ressources on macOS ? Maybe start it in a sandbox mode somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sandbox-exec`

Usage: `sandbox-exec -n no-network someProgram`

Comment: sandbox-exec has been deprecated. Do you know what the replacement is ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no replacement for a single command. If you are developing your own application, you can use `sandbox_init(3)` though.